# SQL Server 2008R2 super high memory consumption - many stolen pages and huge log file

Tags: sql-server

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The SQL instance has 12 GB RAM allocated to it. Currently (and probably typically) we are sitting at 47 concurrent connections. The server has a handful of DBs residing on it, but only one is really used. This db is 33 GBs with a log size of 89 GB.

The server physical memory is steady at 98%, and our application response time is bad. Most of the memory used by SQL Server are stolen pages. I'm not sure how to correct this. Our indexes and statistics are all basically brand new/recently rebuilt.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how stolen pages are occurring, why they remain so high, and how to deal with this. Is the log related? It's nearly 3 times the size of the DB. We're reaching a critical point, so any and all help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server, by default, will take up all memory unless you tell it not to in the properties of the Server in SSMS (Right click the server and choose properties, go to memory on the left and set the max).

For the log file size, it matters how the application is logging.  Right click the database and choose options, look at the recovery model.  I would Google the different types to match the type to your database need.  If it is Full logged and you are not taking Transaction log backups, the log will just grow and grow.  In that case, look at implementing Ole Hallengren's widely used scripting for backups: https://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: Yes, actually that seems to be exactly what's going on! Thanks. It turns out that the log file grew that much because it is in Full Recovery Mode and there has been index/stats maintenance on the database (eg: heavily logged). There also has been no backups of the DB (just the whole VM it resides on) so the log just kept growing. In the process of correcting that now.

However, that still leaves me with the massive RAM issue and stolen pages. I believe that was occurring before the log growth. Do you have any clues on that?

Comment: @scarr030 Apologies for the delay!  The memory issue, please refer to the top part of the answer.  SQL Server will take all the server's memory unless you specify it not to.  You need to specify an amount of memory in MB that allows for about 6-8GB for the OS.  Get overall server RAM, subtract 8 GB, put that into the memory max for SQL Server via SSMS.